# Magento 2 get store configuration in js

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I'm trying to get admin store configuration (core_config_data) in mincart.js file. Is there any method to get this ? like

```
define([
    'storeConfiguration'
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (config, Component, customerData, $, ko, _)
```

eg:

```
config.getBaseUrl or something.. I searched a lot but I couldn't find out anything...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need store configuration values in `minicart.js`. You can get it like this.

I will just try to get store name in minicart.js.

Add below code in minicart.phtml file

```
<script>
   window.getStoreName = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getStoreName(); ?>'
</script>
```

Now for `minicart.phtml` we can use block `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar` so maybe you will need to rewrite it in your custom module. But main thing is that we need to add a function in this class.

Add this in Sidebar.php

```
public function getStoreName()
{
     return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'general/store_information/name',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
     );
}
```

Now you can use `window.getStoreName` in minicart.js to get store name from the admin configuration.

For example - minicart.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var sidebarInitialized = false,
        addToCartCalls = 0,
        miniCart;

    miniCart = $('[data-block=\'minicart\']');

    console.log(window.getStoreName); // you will have store name here
    ...
```

This is just an example to get store name so you can change it depending on what configuration value you want.

Comment: I'm struggling to override minicart.phtml file. So that's the reason I trying to different approach.   All I need is I need to get some store config values in content.html. The content.html is loading from mincart.js.